# Find selected data in excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm seeking a solution below scenario.

`C1` contains:

`['abc': 'v1','cde':'v2']`

`C2` contains:

`['abc': 'v1','cde':'v2','efg':'v3']`

What I expect to get in `D1`:
`abc,cde`
and in `D2` `abc,cde,efg`

I was trying to get the formula as below
=LEFT(C1,FIND(",",C1)-1)
but its coming like "['abc':'v1'

Answer (score 0):

When using Office 365 you can use REDUCE to iterate SUBSTITUTE with multiple characters over multiple cells in one go.
Using REDUCE once more to spill the joined text of the first indexed column of the TEXTSPLIT result per row (this will work regardless the number of seaparators (up untill the string would exceed 255 characters, I guess):

```
=LET(a,C1:C3,
     replace,{"[";"]";" ";"'"},
     rdc,REDUCE(a,replace,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,""))),
DROP(REDUCE(0,rdc,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(y,":",","),,1))))),1))
```

[image]